# Sound from front of bike

Tags: mountain-bike, noise

I am hearing a sound coming from the area around the front rotor. It sounds kind of like the sound a baby bird might make.

It occurs whether I am pedaling or not.

I put some marksalot on the disc on both sides to see if any wore off with me NOT using that brake.

None work off.

Any ideas what to check next?

[image]

Comment: The problem with marking the rotor is that you'd have to mark the whole surface to find the high spots that makes the noise. It's unlikely to be the whole surface. Then when you used the brakes you'd get lots of marker on the pads. Of course it would only be a little marker if you managed to avoid using that brake, perhaps working on a stand, but for very slight rub it's better to test ride with weight on the bike

Answer (score 3):

https://cyclingmagazine.ca/sections/news/silence-your-disc-brakes-and-stop-annoying-your-riding-partners/

The fix was a simple one. I loosened up the brake cable a little.